# Firefox doesn't show the FontAwesome unicode

Tags: css, firefox, unicode, font-awesome

The render of a FontAwesome icon works perfect on Firefox. But when I wanna change it through the inspector (Firebug), it doesn't show the unicode (for example: f066). So where I should have:

```
content:"\f066;
```

It shows:

```
content: "";
```

It is not showing the data correctly. If I overwrite a new one (\f077) it prints nothing. Is it possible to fix it? What I need is to be able to change FontAwesome icons from the inspector, like on Chrome.